# Disqus comment thread telling me to upgrade to IE9 . . . when using IE9

Tags: javascript, html, disqus

Disqus comment thread working really well in all browsers except IE9, where I get an error message telling me to upgrade to IE9.  Any suggestions as to how I might get rid of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it that you're running in a different mode within IE dev tools (press f12 and see what Browser mode and document mode your running under).